# Anonymous function references in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, anonymous-function, mobile-website

I'm currently in the process of building out a VERY simple Observer class for a project I'm working on. I have successfully implemented the subscribe, unsubscribe, and notify methods. Everything works exactly as expected when using "regular" functions (i.e: `var f = function()`).

However, when I pass an anonymous function to the subscribe method and then try to unsubscribe passing the "same" anonymous function it (as expected) doesn't remove the function from my array (they are different, after all).

Here's my subscribe and unsubscribe methods:

```
this._subscribers = {};
subscribe: function(type, callback) {
    if ( isUndefined(this._subscribers[type]) ) {
        this._subscribers[type] = [];
    }
    this._subscribers[type].push(callback);
},
unsubscribe: function(type, callback) {
    if ( this._subscribers[type] instanceof Array ) {
        var index = this._subscribers[type].indexOf(callback);
        if ( index >= 0 ) {
            this._subscribers[type].splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
},
```

And here's the code I'm testing with:

```
var o = new gaf.events.Observable();
o.subscribe('testEvent', function(event) { alert('Got It!'); });
o.notify('testEvent');
// Correct alerts 'Got It!'
o.unsubscribe('testEvent', function(event) { alert('Got It!'); });
o.notify('testEvent')
// Incorrectly alerts 'Got It!'
```

I know I could using an object (i.e.: `_subscribers[event] = {}`) and then when something subscribes I could add a new property equal to the callback and the value equal to the callback. This will cause Javascript to convert the callback to the string. I could then look it up (provided the methods passed in sub/unsub are exactly the same) using that string.

However, this is a mobile project and I'm very leery about storing strings that could be hundreds of characters long as properties as we could end up with a lot of subscribers.

Are there any other ways of doing this? Are there any SMALL (tiny, even) hashing libraries I can use to maybe hash the string value of the function and use that as the property? Would it be better to store the string value of the callback (so I can compare against it) in the array (rather then the actual callback) and use `eval()` on it?

**EDIT**

First, thanks all for the replies!

Per all the questions about "Why even pass anonymous" functions -

There really is no reason one COULDN'T use named functions. In fact, I agree with everyone that named functions are going to be the better solution. I'm simply gathering information and looking for a solution so that I can build out an implementation that handles the most scenarios as best as possible.

The other reason for this is what happens if a user (co-worker) of this Observable class passes it an anonymous function and then unsubscribes. That function won't actually be unsubscribed and therefore won't be cleaned up. I have a thing against orphaned data :)

Maybe another question I should as is, is it possible to test if the callback is anonymous or not? I'm going to assume no but doesn't hurt to ask.

Comment: Being a mobile project, I don't think you want to waste the space by duplicating the anonymous functions (one for subscribe and one for unsubscribe).  Also, you'll need the overhead (both space and performance) for the hashing library.  The hashing library would need to "stringify" the function and then hash it.  The "stringify" operation would need to have white-space properly.  All of this sounds like a headache.  I suggest following the best practice of saving the function to a variable or using a named function.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! This is why I didn't just go ahead and implement a hashing function. The overhead and complexity of that process on a mobile device scared me away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a better solution is to modify the code using your library

```
var f = function() { alert('Got It!'); };
o.subscribe('testEvent', f);
o.notify('testEvent');
o.unsubscribe('testEvent', f);
o.notify('testEvent');
```

You could even return the function from the subscribe method

```
var f = o.subscribe('testEvent', function() { alert('Got It!'); });
// ...
```

then if you want to store a hash or some other identifier for subscribed functions, it is opaque to the calling code meaning that you just use the returned value to unsubscribe and the library hides the implementation detail.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with storing the entire string; premature optimization is evil.

However, this sounds like an incredibly bad idea.
If someone changes the function, but forgets to change the unsubscribed copy, the code will be subtly broken with no warning whatsoever.

Instead, you can require the user to store the anonymous function in a variable if they want to unsubscribe from it.
Alternatively, you can pass an optional name with each subscriber, then unsubscribe by that name.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I agree it's an entirely a bad idea to store the string. I was just throwing out some thoughts I had on the matter :)

Answer (score 1):

the clients that use the Observer should store the reference to the function.

```
   var obsCallback = function() {

   }
   o.subscribe('test', obsCallback);
   ....
   o.unsubscribe('test', obsCallback);
```

in other words, keep a reference to the function around...

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason for passing in anonymous functions rather than named ones, or keeping references that you can use for unsubscribing later?

Alternatively you could allow for an optional 'id' argument but this would require unnecessarily complex bookkeeping to avoid duplicates.